# Bolding text within a string created via StringBuilder in Java

Tags: java

I need to display a string of text with select words in bold. This is for a web application which uses jsf icefaces, but the problem is with the java. The string needs to be passed to the ui already formatted.

It should return a string such as: Hello **Universe!** Greetings Earthing!

Example code:

```
public String displayMessage(){
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Hello");
    sb.append("Universe!");
    sb.append("Greetings Earthing!");
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Everything I've found so far uses either swing, which I *can't* use, or is for android, which I'm obviously not using. I've tried html tags, but it obviously doesn't work. I've also tried String.format() with html tags and Font.BOLD, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Help?

Comment: Where you would like to output it? In the html page it may look bold as: `sb.append("<b>Universe!</b>");`

Comment: Strings are just plain text. You'd need to decorate it yourself depending on for format in which you intend it to be rendered.

Comment: I suppose that when you try to insert HTML markup into your string that it gets escaped and presented as text.  You have not shown how the string is being inserted into the page, so we can't help you with specifics, but you are looking for a way to suppress the HTML escaping.

Comment: _"I've tried html tags, but it obviously doesn't work."_ what does that mean?

Comment: If you're targeting HTML, I would recommend that you take a look at the HTML reference on http://www.w3schools.com. You're going to have to deal with HTML and CSS, like it or not. :)

Comment: Yes, the tags just gets displayed as plain text. Sorry, I'm not permitted to post the actual code. The string is getting passed to a display area that only displays text when a test fails. This area is populated from a list of string objects and not all strings in the list need emphasis in the same places. The formatting for the string cannot happen at this point, so it has to happen when the string is created. All of the files for the ui functionality are xhtml, not html, since this is being programmed and controlled through in jsf.

Comment: *The formatting for the string cannot happen at this point, so it has to happen when the string is created.*  Fantastic.  Then you and the display program programmer have to agree on some kind of text markup.  HTML is already defined.